# com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.18:update failed. NoSuchElementException ->

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

I am new to Google Drive API and getting following error while setting a sample Guestbook application in Eclipse. I have read almost all the questions that are posted here about this error but I still the error. Hence I am writing this question.

The error I am seeing is -

```
Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.18:update (default-cli) on project guestbook: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.18:update failed. NoSuchElementException ->
```

I am seeing this error when I am performing step 2:
Run the app in the development server on your local machine by invoking this command from /guestbook: mvn appengine:devserver

[Building and testing the app - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/ui_and_code]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I fixed this issue -

1. I manually added appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.18.jar into java build path.
2. I manually added JRE system library(JavaSE-1.7) into the build path. Initially it was JDK.
3. In java build path - order and export tab,
   manually moved above mentioed jar to the up, so that Eclipse will know which jar to take while compiling the project.

By implementing all the steps mentioned above, I got able to deploy Guestbook application and was able to run it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the `1.9.18` version is not yet available in Maven repositories. Try to downgrade to `1.9.17` and check if it solves the problem.

Comment: I am sorry to say tomrozb - but I still see the error.